# Dart Empty response sent by client HttpRequest

Tags: dart, httprequest, orientdb, dart-html

I'm trying to query OrientDB in a Dart web client, and it seems to be sending an empty response. Here is my main.dart:

```
import 'dart:html';
// import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
 // querySelector('#output').text = 'Your Dart app is running.';
  HttpRequest.request("http://localhost:2480/listDatabases", 
      method: 'GET', requestHeaders: 
          {'Access-Contol-Allow-Origin': '*'})
  .then((req) => req.onReadyStateChange.where((e) => 
      req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE).first
  .then((e) {
    var resp = req.responseText;
    querySelector('#output').text = "${req.status}";
    Map json = JSON.decode(resp);
    var ul = querySelector('#dblist');
    for (var db in json['databases']) {
      var li = new LIElement();
      li.appendText(db);
      ul.append(li);
    }
  }));
}
```

and here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
  Copyright (c) 2015, <your name>. All rights reserved. Use of this source code
  is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
-->

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
    <title>WebDbList1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script async src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="output"></div>
  <ul id="dblist">

  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

If there is any question about the OrientDB-specific code, the following successfully retrieves a database list...

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

const String database = "dosdart1";

main(List<String> args) async {
  List dblist = new List();
  String firstName, lastName;
  print("First name?");
  firstName = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Last name?");
  lastName = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("You entered $firstName $lastName");
  dblist = await ListDatabases();
  print("received $dblist");

  // send GET http://localhost:2480/listDatabases
  /*
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://localhost:2480/listDatabases"))
  .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    return request.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
      print("$contents");
      Map json = JSON.decode(contents);
      List dblist = json["databases"];
      if (dblist.contains("dosdart1")) {
        print("database exists");
      } else {
        print("Creating database...");

      }
      print("Found $dblist");

    });
  });
  */
}

Future<List> ListDatabases() {
  var completer = new Completer();
  List dblist = new List();

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://localhost:2480/listDatabases"))
  .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    return request.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
      //    print("$contents");
      Map json = JSON.decode(contents);
      print("$json");
      for (var db in json['databases']) {
        dblist.add(db);
        print("$db");
      }
    //  print("$dblist");
      completer.complete(dblist);
    });
  });
  return completer.future;


}
```

What I'm trying to do is retrieve a list of existing databases from OreintDB and display it on my browser. I can achieve this end in that command-line app, but I keep failing in a web client. Any suggestions? My code compiles OK, but all I get is a blank web page on Dartium.

Comment: If you enter this url http://localhost:2480/listDatabases directly into the browser url bar you get the expected response?

Comment: I wonder why you set the "Access-Contol-Allow-Origin" header on client side, you should set it on server side. Maybe you run into the same origin policy?

Comment: I misspelled "control" in the header, but fixing that typo didn't fix the problem. There is no "server" in this case except for the OrientDB database server. Entering "localhost:2480/listDatabases" in a browser gets the desired results. I'm trying to use OrientDB's REST interface.

Comment: @Fox32 I was trying to avoid the "same origin policy" issue.

Comment: @RossAlbertson You have to configure "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on the server side. You find an explanation here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/orient-database/vjOoxKwNv34/T0Cg2o3tO6AJ

Comment: @Fox32 I discovered something strange. The following will work, but only in IE: `import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

processString() async {
  var response = await HttpRequest.getString('http://localhost:2480/listDatabases');
  Map json = JSON.decode(response);
  List list = new List();
  for (var db in json['databases']) {
    list.add(db);
  }
  return list;
}


main() async {
  var list = await processString();
  var ul = querySelector('#dblist');
  list.forEach((db) {
    var li = new LIElement();
    li.appendText(db);
    ul.append(li);

});
}`

Comment: @Fox32 I modified that XML config file according to your link, but I'm not entirely sure I did it right. What I did didn't fix the problem. Are the new parameter key-value tags supposed to be in a separate <parameters> node or the same one as the UTF8 setter? My sequential DOM manipulation works but the async doesn't...except in Microsoft browsers (those work just fine). Does the fact I'm using Windows have anything to do with the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the configuration XML fix I was given, changed my div tag to ul, and the following Dart gave me my OrientDB database list

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var root = querySelector('#output') as UListElement;
  HttpRequest.getString("http://localhost:2480/listDatabases").then((content) {
    var raw = JSON.decode(content);
    List databases = raw['databases'];
    for (String database in databases) {
      var li = new LIElement();
      li.appendText(database);
      root.append(li);
    }
  });
}
```

I inserted the following into orient-server-config.xml as I was told:

```
<parameter value="Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:63342;Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true;Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin;Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTION" name="network.http.additionalResponseHeaders"/>
```

Comment: @Fox32 My apologies! I figured out how to configure OrientDB like you said, and my code gives the response

{"@type":"d","@version":0,"databases":["GratefulDeadConcerts"],"@fieldTypes":"databases=e"}

My new Dart code is 


import 'dart:html';

main() async {
//  querySelector('#output').text = 'Your Dart app is running.';
  var request = await HttpRequest.request('http://localhost:2480/listDatabases', mimeType: "application/json");
  querySelector('#output').text = request.responseText;
}

and my new config XML is

Comment: My new XML is
`<parameters>
                    <parameter name="network.http.additionalResponseHeaders" value="Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:63342;Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true;Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin;Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTION" />
        <parameter value="utf-8" name="network.http.charset"/>
                    <parameter value="true" name="network.http.jsonResponseError"/>
                </parameters>`

Comment: After the previously mentioned configuration hack, the following Dart code got the expected results:
`import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  var root = querySelector('#output') as UListElement;  HttpRequest.getString("http://localhost:2480/listDatabases").then((content) {
    var raw = JSON.decode(content);
    List databases = raw['databases'];
...
`